# Node.js - read data from super user directory

Tags: node.js, docker, fs, ubuntu-18.04, readdir

I want to read data from a docker container which is located in

`/var/lib/docker/containers/<name>/log.json`

In terminal, when I am in `/var/lib/docker/`, in order to use `ls` or `cd` commands, I must first `sudo su`

How can I get my Node application to do the same? Currently I get

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir '/var/lib/docker/containers'
```

when I run my code

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    return fs.readdir(`/var/lib/docker/containers`, (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      } else {
        resolve(data);
      }
    });
  });
```

Comment: Are you running this within a docker container or on the host machine?  You'll need to run the code as a super user to access the folder owned by root.  If in a docker container, you can set the [user in the Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#user) if on the host, you'll have to `sudo my-program.js`.

Comment: Im running in a container and I followed the method in the docs. I should have mentioned that my Dockerfile calls a shell script and that shell script calls `node someFunction()` - so even though my container is now `sudo` that function call is not

Comment: Usually you don't try to do things like this at all: talk to the Docker daemon using [its API](https://docs.docker.com/develop/sdk/) if you want to do things like list containers.  This will still require root-equivalent privilege.  (It's the same class of question as "I'm running a database, how do I directly read the files in `/var/lib/mysql`?" with the same answer "it's complicated and the file format isn't guaranteed to be stable long-term".)